# Relying upon circular reference is discouraged and they are prohibited by default in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring

Hello guys Im new to using spring I'm trying to create a login registration page but I'm facing this error. The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

```
┌─────┐
|  securityConfiguration defined in file 
[C:\Users\hp\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-     
4.20.0.RELEASE\springboot-registeration-login-3\target\classes\net\javaguides\springboot\config\SecurityConfiguration.class]
↑     ↓
|  userServiceImpl defined in file 
[C:\Users\hp\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4- 4.20.0.    
RELEASE\springboot-registeration-login-3\target\classes\net\javaguides\springboot\service\UserServiceImpl.class]
└─────┘
```

Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.

That's my userservice implementation part for password encoder:
private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

```
@Autowired
public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
this.userRepository = userRepository;
this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }``
```

and thats for the security config:
public class SecurityConfiguration {

```
private final UserService userService;

public SecurityConfiguration(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

I have tried allowing circular dependency but Im getting this error Despite circular references being allowed, the dependency cycle between beans could not be broken. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Hi yes circular reference is discouraged because it indicates some bad design in the system. Although in your case I think you can declare your PasswordEncoder Bean in another class, that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to create either a `UserServiceImpl` or a `SecurityConfiguration` object without having already created the other:

- To create a `UserServiceImpl` Spring needs to call its constructor `UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder)` which it can only do after it has created a `PasswordEncoder` object.
- To create a `PasswordEncoder` object Spring has to call `SecurityConfiguration.passwordEncoder()` which it can only do after it has created a `SecurityConfiguration` object.
- To create a `SecurityConfiguration` Spring needs to call its constructor `SecurityConfiguration(UserService userService)` which it can only do after it has created a `UserServiceImpl` object.

You can solve this problem by defining both the `PasswordEncoder` and the `UserServiceImpl` as beans in the `SecurityConfiguration`:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public UserService userService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        return new UserServiceImpl(userRepository, passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```